# Cannot boot installed RHEL 7.1 with extlinux (syslinux)

Tags: linux, operating-system, rhel7, syslinux

I am trying to instal RHEL 7.1 with option

```
bootloader --location=mbr --append="console=ttyS0" --extlinux
```

in kickstart config file. The installation is made on virtual machine QEMU KVM.

```
No DEFAULT or UI configuration Directive found!  
boot:
```

Answer (score 1):

that error tells you that the syslinux configuration file does not define a DEFAULT action neither the UI (i.e. vesamenu) used for displaying a menu.

Comment: Great. That sucks. It seems that RHEL/Centos neither has any extlinux-update utility or os-proper like in Ubuntu/Debian to add the kernels automatically. Stupid. Because there is a flag in kickstart I would expect existence of such mechanism.